SharePoint API call over multiple lists to return one array
I have four SharePoint document lists that I need to find any document that is specially marked. I want to combine the results into one array and return JSON to a javascript file to format the data to add to a webpage. I know at this point three of the lists do not have any documents marked, so they will have null as a result. When I call the function I get "ArrayArrayArray{meeting document list results from the one list that has items}. Javascript does not recognize that as JSON. It seems that the full array I made at the beginning is not combining the arrays at the end but trying to send four.
SOLVED:
Turns out that the SharePoint person forgot to add the Special Marked column to the other lists which was returning the error. Once those lists were updated the function worked. Thank you to all those that commented on this.
public function getSpecalMarkedDocuments() {
    $fullDocumentResults = [];
    $documentLists = ['List1', 'List2', 'List3', 'List4'];

    foreach ($documentLists as $list) {
        Code here that formats the Sharepoint API $url call which works fine
        $results = publicCallAPI($url);

        if (is_null($results) {
        // I have added echo $documentLists here and it will return the three empty list names.
        } else {
        foreach ($results as $items) {
           $meetingDate = $items['Meeting'];
           $filename = $items['File']['Name'];
           $filepath = $items['PubLink'];

           $fullDocumentResults[$meetingDate] = [$filename, $filepath];
        }
    }
    return new JsonResponse($fullDocumentResults);
}

instead of a single JSON list, I get:
ArrayArrayArray{"meeting date1":["filename1", "filepath1"], "meeting date2":["filename2", "filepath2"]}
console.log says:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'A', " ArrayArray"... is not valid JSON
var_dump($results) is:
    array (size=4)
        0 => 
            array (size=4)
              'File' => 
                array (size=2)
                  '__metadata' => 
                    array (size=3)
                      ...
                      'Name' => string 'Name of document here' (length=51)
                      'Meeting' => string '2024-04-04T07:00:00Z' (length=20)
                      'PubLink' => string 'link is here' (length=121)

      1 => 
          array (size=4)
              'File' => 
                array (size=2)
                  '__metadata' => 
                    array (size=3)
                      ...
                      'Name' => string 'document name here' (length=52)
                      'Meeting' => string '2024-04-11T07:00:00Z' (length=20)
         
                      'PubLink' => string 'Link is here' (length=121)
 
      2 => 
            array (size=4)
              'File' => 
                array (size=2)
              '__metadata' => 
                array (size=3)
                  ...
                  'Name' => string 'Document name here' (length=36)
                  'Meeting' => string '2024-04-19T07:00:00Z' (length=20)
                  'PubLink' => string 'Link to document' (length=121)
 
      3 => 
        array (size=4)
              'File' => 
                array (size=2)
              '__metadata' => 
                array (size=3)
                  ...
                  'Name' => string 'Document name here' (length=52)
                  'Meeting' => string '2024-04-11T07:00:00Z' (length=20)
                  'PubLink' => string 'link to document' (length=121)

    Array
        /Controller/SharepointGetDocs.php:799:null
    Array
        /Controller/SharepointGetDocs.php:799:null
    Array
        /Controller/SharepointGetDocs.php:799:null

var_dump($fullDocumentResults) is:
 ArrayArrayArray<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>/Controller/SharepointGetDocs.php:779:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=3)</i>
    '2024-04-04T07:00:00Z': 
        <b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
            0 <'document name'>
            1 <'link to document'>
    '2024-04-11T07:00:00Z': 
        <b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
            0 <'document name'
            1 <'link to document'>
    '2024-04-19T07:00:00Z':
        <b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
            0 <'document name'>
            1 <'link to document'>

I've determined that is is coming from the publicCallAPI function.
$results = curl_exec($ch);
$resultsJSON = json_decode($results, true);
curl_close($ch);
$data = $resultsJSON['d']['results'];
return $data;

I did a var_dump on $data and is shows up there along with the data I want
Array
/home/e3vspcbans2b/public_html/modules/custom/sharepoint_interface/sharepoint_interface.module:143:null
Array
/home/e3vspcbans2b/public_html/modules/custom/sharepoint_interface/sharepoint_interface.module:143:null
Array
/home/e3vspcbans2b/public_html/modules/custom/sharepoint_interface/sharepoint_interface.module:143:null

The word Array on each null is being passed to the JSON which is giving me the error.
I tried
if (empty($data)) {
    $data = [];
}

but it still passes along the Array string.

Why don't you check if your critical array keys are set, and if they're not, continue? That way, your JSON response will only contain meaningful data. Unless you also need to return the empty documents, and let the users know that those are empty.

The documents are filtered with the API call. It will only return documents that have a box marked special on it. I know that at this point, three of the list do not have a document (but will in the future) with that checked box so it will return nothing and I do not need the users to know that those are empty. I guess what I'm trying to figure out is why am I getting four arrays at the end (three empty and one with documents) instead of just the one $fullDocumentResutls array with the content that was found.

Can you post what JsonResponse function looks like?

It uses Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse; https://phpdox.net/demo/Symfony2/classes/Symfony_Component_HttpFoundation_JsonResponse.xhtml

It doesn't seem like JsonResponse is to blame. The end result with it is: {"":[null,null],"meeting date1":["filename1","filepath1"]}, which is the same as with echo json_encode($fullDocumentsResults). Can you edit your question, and post the outcome of var_dump($results) and var_dump($fullDocumentsResults)?

Interesting that the ArrayArrayArray is present in var_dump($results) (bottom of the dump). I do apologize for the constant questions, but can you share your publicCallAPI function? Also (and I should have asked this at the very start), are there any warnings in your PHP error log file (assuming your error logging is enabled)?

the publicCallApi formats the token needed by Sharepoint to authorize the request.

I find this question Unclear because I don't understand if your posted code or unposted code creates the 3 Array  strings.

List 1 has four documents that are marked special. Those documents are returned correctly. List2, 3 and 4 at this point do not have any documents marked special thus they return null. Those three null lists are returning ArrayArrayArray and causing the issue. I'm wondering why. The code above says if the results are null (which is true for 2-4) do nothing. Yet I'm getting something.

// I have added echo $documentLists here and it will return the three empty list names. - no, it won't. $documentLists is the array you are iterating over there, and if you echo that, the result will be the word Array. And that's why you got ArrayArrayArray before your var_dump of the function's return value.

I echoed only as a test to verify that those Arrays were from the three empty lists. Once I verified that I removed that line of code. It still give the ArrayArrayArray without the echo line.

"the publicCallApi formats the token needed by Sharepoint to authorize the request." - The reason I asked is because the function's result is assigned to $result. I was curious whether it echoes anything, and whether it might be the cause of what you're facing.

I believe you are right FiddlingAway. I did a var_dump on the $results in the publicAPI can and it shows up there. I added the code to the question.

I did in the opening paragraph it says SOLVED. Turns out the SharePoint admin did not add the search toggle column to all of the lists. Once he added the search toggle to all the lists it work just as it should.
